# jQuery won't work when we open the file by double clicking on it

Tags: jquery, html

I have noticed that few jQuery events wont work when i open my HTML file in browser by double clicking on it.

```
file:///C:/xampp/htdocs/project/test.html
```

When i access same file through localhost, it works perfectly

```
localhost/project/test.html
```

Can any body tell why this happens?

Comment: Please make sure your jquery "src" is correct!

Comment: Nobody can tell since we're not at your machine. However, if you gave us something useful, like the errors in the console, we might get somewhere...

Comment: What message do you get in the browser when you double click on the file?  This is a browser issue.  Definitely not Apache/IIS, since it works on your localhost, and not simply in your browser when navigating to the absolute path in your file system.

Comment: my html file contains bare HTML. There is no errors, When i open my file through localhost jQuery works perfectly. When i open same file like normal HTML file by double clicking on it, jQuery wont work!

Comment: I think your Jquery library file location not founded, and what is the error you got?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the times this happens when you load jQuery from an external source like from Microsoft or Google. When you double click your html file, cross site scripting prevents it to load sources from these Google or Microsoft domains. When you load it from localhost, this is allowed. That is why it works on localhost and not when you double click the file.